# ggplot2 facet_wrap doesn't find a variable but shape does

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm running in a bit of a problem plotting some data with `ggplot2`: I want to use a `facet_wrap` over a variable `AdultInputProp`, but R doesn't find the variable and instead returns an `Error in as.quoted(facets) : object 'AdultInputProp' not found`. Now I understand that this simply means that R can't find this variable in the dataset used to plot, **but** if I ask `ggplot2` to instead use the same variable for to create a `shape` scale, it works just fine. Any idea what the problem might be?

Sorry, I'm not too sure how to make a minimal working example with a generated df from scratch, so here's [the df I'm using](https://lancaster.box.com/s/d4483kfy514sv94iypijhyt5ksocyd2j), and the code bellow. I've also tried using `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap` but ran into the same problem.

The code here with facets returns the above-mentioned error:

```
df.plot.GBPperAIP <- ggplot(df.sum.GBPperAIP,
                            aes(x=TestIteration, y=Error,
                                colour=GoalBabblingProp,
                                group=interaction(GoalBabblingProp,
                                                  AdultInputProp))) +
  facet_wrap(AdultInputProp) +
  xlab("Step") + ylab("Mean error") + theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Goal babbling proportion") +
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(1000)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Error-ci,
                    ymax=Error+ci),
                color="black", width=1000,
                position = position_dodge(1000)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(1000),
             size=1.5, fill="white")
```

This other code, exactly the same except for the `facet_wrap` line deleted and with `shape` added works fine:

```
df.plot.GBPperAIP <- ggplot(df.sum.GBPperAIP,
                            aes(x=TestIteration, y=Error,
                                colour=GoalBabblingProp,
                                shape=AdultInputProp,
                                group=interaction(GoalBabblingProp,
                                                  AdultInputProp))) +
  xlab("Step") + ylab("Mean error") + theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Goal babbling proportion") +
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(1000)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Error-ci,
                    ymax=Error+ci),
                color="black", width=1000,
                position = position_dodge(1000)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(1000),
             size=1.5, fill="white")
```

Comment: `facet_wrap(~ AdultInputProp)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`facet_wrap` expects a formula, not just a naked variable name. So you should change it to

```
...
facet_wrap(~ AdultInputProp) +
...
```

Comment: Stupidly I had tried using `facet_wrap(.~AdultInputProp)` and hadn't understood the error. Then stupidly hadn't tried it with `facet_grid`, where I guess it should have worked. Still annoyed by how hard R errors are to read for me!